# How can I create a script with for loop in linux that would edit files differently

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have 10 files and I need a script that can, for example, write numbers from 1 to 10 in each file so that in one file would be written one number. I tried doing like this, but it doesn't work:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    
    for (( i=1; i<=10; i++ )); do
    cat file$i
    $i
    done
```

Comment: each number should contain different number from 1 to 10

Comment: If you want to modify/clarify your question please edit the question itself. Comments may change or disappear at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean each file, say `1.txt`, contains `1` in it? Then this may work:

```
 #!/bin/bash
    
for i in {1..10}; do
     echo $i > ${i}.txt
done
```

Comment: each file should contain different number from 1 to 10

Comment: The above would result in `1.txt` contains `1`, `2.txt` contains `2`, and so on.